# Netsuite reconfigure inventory detail error

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

On a custom record creation i am calling a map reduce script that in creating a negative inventory adjustment.
The script is called on after submit.
I am using following code to populate the inventory detail subrecords

```
for (var n = 0; n < cp_lotsearch.length; n++) {
                    if (cree_onhand > 0) {
                        var cp_lotid = cp_lotsearch[n].getValue({name: 'internalid'});
                        var cp_parentcasenum = cp_lotsearch[n].getValue({name: 'custrecord_nsts_ia_lot'});
                        var itemsearch = search.create({
                            type: 'item',
                            filters: ['inventorynumber.inventorynumber', 'is', cp_parentcasenum],
                            columns: [search.createColumn({name: "quantityonhand", join: "inventorynumber"})]
                        }).run().getRange({
                            start: 0,
                            end: 1000
                        });
                        var qtyonhand = itemsearch[0].getValue({name: 'quantityonhand', join: 'inventorynumber'});
                        var remain_qtyonhand = Number(qtyonhand) - Number(cree_onhand);
                        if (remain_qtyonhand >= 0) {
                            var reduceqty = 0 - Number(cree_onhand);
                        } else {
                            var reduceqty = 0 - Number(qtyonhand);
                        }
                        log.debug("reduceqty", reduceqty);
                        subrecord.insertLine({sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',line: n});

                        subrecord.setSublistText({ sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',fieldId: 'issueinventorynumber',line: n,text: cp_parentcasenum});
                        subrecord.setSublistValue({sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',fieldId: 'binnumber', line: n, value: cree_bin});
                        subrecord.setSublistValue({sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',fieldId: 'quantity',line: n,value: reduceqty});
                        log.debug("reduceqty added to inventory detail", reduceqty);
                        cree_onhand = Number(cree_onhand) + Number(reduceqty);
                        
                    }
                }
                var invadjid = parentcase_inv_Adj.save({
                    enableSourcing: true,
                    ignoreMandatoryFields: true
                });
```

When i try to run this code i am getting following error:

**"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"USER_ERROR","message":"You still need to reconfigure the inventory detail record after changing the quantity."**

Same code is running perfect in sandbox account but in production it is throwing error

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

I Got one solution in suite answer that i already tried but it is not working here is link to it:
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/80790/kw/reconfigure%20error

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered this error can be triggered server-side if :

- multiple units of measure feature is enabled.
- the *stock* units of measure are not 1-to-1, i.e. the receipt unit is in packs of 20, but the base unit of the UOM is 1's.
- the item is serialised.

However, if the same is attempted client-side, the error becomes "The total inventory detail quantity must be XX" (XX being the quantity set in "adjustqtyby" on the inventory adjustment line).